# How to reference XML file which is in rich text box and order by DateTime

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file (in a rich-text box) which should be ordered by datetime and duplicate data should be deleted.

I don't how to reference and order such an XML file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // open file dialog works fine
{
    Stream myStream;

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files(.xml)|*.xml|all Files(*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
            richTextBox1.Text = filetext;
            MessageBox.Show(strfilename);
        }
    }
}

//Deleting  duplicate data
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\21.xml");// do i need to use this line.
    doc.Root.Elements("Incident")
    .GroupBy(s => (string)s.Element("Comment"))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .Remove();

    //doc.Save(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\2014-01-07_Middlesex.xml");

    //doc.Save(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\22.xml");
}

//saving..
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //doc.Save(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\22.xml");
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files(.xml)|*.xml|all Files(*.*)|*.*";
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
        {
            sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my full xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Incidents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Count="34" Date="2014-01-07" Time="09:54:00" FileName="2014-01-07_Middlesex..xml">
  <Incident>
    <Contract>18</Contract>
    <SerialNo>0000000001</SerialNo>
    <EntryTime>2013-12-31T00:13:23</EntryTime>
    <ExitTime>2013-12-31T01:00:47</ExitTime>
    <OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode>
    <Operator>P+D</Operator>
    <Registration>LS5VP</Registration>
    <Location> Middlesex</Location>
    <Make>N/A</Make>
    <Model>N/A</Model>
    <Colour>N/A</Colour>
    <Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 00:13:23
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 01:00:47</Comment>
    <Nationality>-1</Nationality>
    <Foreign>-1</Foreign>
    <Evidence>
      <FileName>entry_143_LS5VP_2014-01-07_09-54-00.jpg</FileName>
      <FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription>
    </Evidence>
    <Evidence>
      <FileName>exit_143_LS5VP_2014-01-07_09-54-00.jpg</FileName>
      <FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription>
    </Evidence>
    <Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic>
  </Incident>
<Incident><Contract>18</Contract><SerialNo>0000000002</SerialNo><EntryTime>2013-12-31T00:13:23</EntryTime><ExitTime>2013-12-31T01:00:47</ExitTime><OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode><Operator>P+D</Operator><Registration>LS5VP</Registration><Location> Middlesex</Location><Make>N/A</Make><Model>N/A</Model><Colour>N/A</Colour><Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 00:13:23
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 01:00:47</Comment><Nationality>-1</Nationality><Foreign>-1</Foreign><Evidence><FileName>entry_143_LS5VP_2014-01-07_09-55-30.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription></Evidence><Evidence><FileName>exit_143_LS5VP_2014-01-07_09-55-30.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription></Evidence><Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic></Incident><Incident><Contract>18</Contract><SerialNo>0000000003</SerialNo><EntryTime>2013-12-31T00:13:23</EntryTime><ExitTime>2013-12-31T01:00:47</ExitTime><OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode><Operator>P+D</Operator><Registration>LS5VP</Registration><Location> Middlesex</Location><Make>N/A</Make><Model>N/A</Model><Colour>N/A</Colour><Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 00:13:23
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 01:00:47</Comment><Nationality>-1</Nationality><Foreign>-1</Foreign><Evidence><FileName>entry_143_LS5VP_2014-01-07_09-56-33.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription></Evidence><Evidence><FileName>exit_143_LS5VP_2014-01-07_09-56-33.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription></Evidence><Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic></Incident><Incident><Contract>18</Contract><SerialNo>0000000004</SerialNo><EntryTime>2013-12-31T10:48:56</EntryTime><ExitTime>2013-12-31T12:12:02</ExitTime><OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode><Operator>P+D</Operator><Registration>LY0XR</Registration><Location> Middlesex</Location><Make>N/A</Make><Model>N/A</Model><Colour>N/A</Colour><Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 10:48:56
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 12:12:02</Comment><Nationality>-1</Nationality><Foreign>-1</Foreign><Evidence><FileName>entry_143_LY0XR_2014-01-07_09-57-22.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription></Evidence><Evidence><FileName>exit_143_LY0XR_2014-01-07_09-57-22.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription></Evidence><Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic></Incident><Incident><Contract>18</Contract><SerialNo>0000000032</SerialNo><EntryTime>2013-12-31T19:11:34</EntryTime><ExitTime>2013-12-31T19:36:17</ExitTime><OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode><Operator>P+D</Operator><Registration>AK1DX</Registration><Location> Middlesex</Location><Make>N/A</Make><Model>N/A</Model><Colour>N/A</Colour><Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 19:11:34
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 19:36:17</Comment><Nationality>-1</Nationality><Foreign>-1</Foreign><Evidence><FileName>entry_143_AK1DX_2014-01-07_10-32-40.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription></Evidence><Evidence><FileName>exit_143_AK1DX_2014-01-07_10-32-40.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription></Evidence><Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic></Incident><Incident><Contract>18</Contract><SerialNo>0000000033</SerialNo><EntryTime>2013-12-31T19:11:34</EntryTime><ExitTime>2013-12-31T19:36:17</ExitTime><OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode><Operator>P+D</Operator><Registration>AK1DX</Registration><Location> Middlesex</Location><Make>N/A</Make><Model>N/A</Model><Colour>N/A</Colour><Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 19:11:34
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 19:36:17</Comment><Nationality>-1</Nationality><Foreign>-1</Foreign><Evidence><FileName>entry_143_AK1DX_2014-01-07_10-33-29.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription></Evidence><Evidence><FileName>exit_143_AK1DX_2014-01-07_10-33-29.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription></Evidence><Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic></Incident><Incident><Contract>18</Contract><SerialNo>0000000034</SerialNo><EntryTime>2013-12-31T20:22:33</EntryTime><ExitTime>2013-12-31T22:57:48</ExitTime><OffenceCode>94</OffenceCode><Operator>P+D</Operator><Registration>MK0HL</Registration><Location> Middlesex</Location><Make>N/A</Make><Model>N/A</Model><Colour>N/A</Colour><Comment>Entry Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 20:22:33
Exit Date: Tuesday, 31 12 2013 on 22:57:48</Comment><Nationality>-1</Nationality><Foreign>-1</Foreign><Evidence><FileName>entry_143_MK0HL_2014-01-07_10-34-19.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Entry</FileDescription></Evidence><Evidence><FileName>exit_143_MK0HL_2014-01-07_10-34-19.jpg</FileName><FileDescription>Exit</FileDescription></Evidence><Diplomatic>0</Diplomatic></Incident></Incidents>
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the XML file.